# Setting data to a nodePtr without overwriting

Tags: c, struct, binary, nodes

Okay so i would like to know how to set a data structure that has other types of data such as road or city inside the struct but it doesnt have an array for the struct data type.

```
   Struct data
    {
     Char city[MAX_LENGTH];
     Char road[MAX_LENGTH];
     }
```

In main:
          Data data;  //just dont want to change the name 
I know how to init a node insert a node etc...but when it comes to adding more info i dont,understand...
 And when i read a binary file. It reads through said struct and i want to add more to the binary file without overwriting it. and im not sure how i would add to it by using a node. Any ideas?

Basic description:
I need to add. A city and a road without overwriting what is in the binary file.

Comment: You need to clarify your issue and with what you need help.  I can't really understand it the way you've written it here.

Comment: @jschultz410 i put a basic description let me know if it makes more sense

Comment: @jschultz410 thanks! Oh and i wasnt haveing capitilization issues i had typed this pn ny phone so it decided to auto capitilize :P but thanks for pointing it out i know c doesnt allow it haha

Comment: @jschultz410 what is r+ and a by the way?

Comment: Those are different modes of operation.  "r+" means open the file for reading and writing.  Reads and writes will occur wherever the file pointer currently is.  "a" means open for append writing.  All writes will append onto the end of the file.  "a+" means open for reading and append writing.  You can reposition the file pointer and read from elsewhere in the file, but all writes will append onto the end of the file.

Comment: @jschultz410 okay but i need to do it in binary i know i have to use wb and rb, is there a way to use fseek with it?

Comment: The "b" modes have no effect on most systems.  You probably want to use "r+b" as "w" first truncates (i.e. - empties) the file you open.  fseek will work fine with either modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have trouble with your capitalization, which actually matters in C:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 50

struct data
{
  char city[MAX_LENGTH];
  char road[MAX_LENGTH];
};

int main()
{
  struct data data;

  return 0;
}
```

You can write to a binary file without overwriting it by opening it using either of:

```
FILE *fp  = fopen(filename, "r+b");
FILE *fp2 = fopen(filename, "ab");  // "a+b" will also work
```

With the first version, your file pointer will be at the very beginning of the file, so you will likely need to seek to wherever it is you want to write:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
```

With the second version, your file pointer will be at the very end of the file and any writes will be appended onto the end of the file.

PS - The "b"'s in the modes above indicate the file is binary, but often have no effect on many systems (i.e. - quietly ignored).